# After training my own classifier with nltk, how do I load it in textblob?

Tags: python, nltk, naivebayes, textblob

The built-in classifier in textblob is pretty dumb. It's trained on movie reviews, so I created a huge set of examples in my context (57,000 stories, categorized as positive or negative) and then trained it using `nltk.` I tried using textblob to train it but it always failed:

```
with open('train.json', 'r') as fp:
    cl = NaiveBayesClassifier(fp, format="json")
```

That would run for hours and end in a memory error.

I looked at the source and found it was just using nltk and wrapping that, so I used that instead, and it worked.

The structure for nltk training set needed to be a list of tuples, with the first part was a Counter of words in the text and frequency of appearance. The second part of tuple was 'pos' or 'neg' for sentiment.

```
>>> train_set = [(Counter(i["text"].split()),i["label"]) for i in data[200:]]
>>> test_set = [(Counter(i["text"].split()),i["label"]) for i in data[:200]] # withholding 200 examples for testing later

>>> cl = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set) # <-- this is the same thing textblob was using

>>> print("Classifier accuracy percent:",(nltk.classify.accuracy(cl, test_set))*100)
('Classifier accuracy percent:', 66.5)
>>>>cl.show_most_informative_features(75)
```

Then I pickled it.

```
with open('storybayes.pickle','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(cl,f)
```

Now... I took this pickled file, and re opened it to get the nltk.classifier 'nltk.classify.naivebayes.NaiveBayesClassifier'> -- and tried to feed it into textblob. Instead of

```
from textblob.classifiers import NaiveBayesClassifier
blob = TextBlob("I love this library", analyzer=NaiveBayesAnalyzer())
```

I tried:

```
blob = TextBlob("I love this library", analyzer=myclassifier)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#116>", line 1, in <module>
    blob = TextBlob("I love this library", analyzer=cl4)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\textblob\blob.py", line 369, in __init__
    parser, classifier)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\textblob\blob.py", line 323, in 
_initialize_models
    BaseSentimentAnalyzer, BaseBlob.analyzer)
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\textblob\blob.py", line 305, in 
_validated_param
    .format(name=name, cls=base_class_name))
ValueError: analyzer must be an instance of BaseSentimentAnalyzer
```

what now? I looked at the source and both are classes, but not quite exactly the same.

Comment: textblob's classifier creates a class: `classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier(train) >> <class 'textblob.classifiers.NaiveBayesClassifier'>` and nltk's classifier creates a class: `<class 'nltk.classify.naivebayes.NaiveBayesClassifier'>` -- so stuck on how to make nltk's work in textblob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another more forward-looking solution is to use spaCy to build the model instead of `textblob` or `nltk`. This is new to me, but seems a lot easier to use and more powerful:
https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101#section-lightning-tour

> "spaCy is the Ruby of Rails of natural language processing."

```
import spacy
import random

nlp = spacy.load('en') # loads the trained starter model here
train_data = [("Uber blew through $1 million", {'entities': [(0, 4, 'ORG')]})] # better model stuff

with nlp.disable_pipes(*[pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']):
    optimizer = nlp.begin_training()
    for i in range(10):
        random.shuffle(train_data)
        for text, annotations in train_data:
            nlp.update([text], [annotations], sgd=optimizer)
nlp.to_disk('/model')
```

Comment: Update: one year later, I rely on Spacy for solving these types of problems, not nltk, in general.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to be certain that a nltk corpus cannot work with textblob, and that would surprise me since textblob imports all of the nltk functions in its source code, and is basically a wrapper.

But what I did conclude after many hours of testing is that nltk offers a better built-in sentiment corpus called `"vader"` that outperformed all of my trained models.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('vader_lexicon') # do this once: grab the trained model from the web
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
Analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
Analyzer.polarity_scores("I find your lack of faith disturbing.")
{'neg': 0.491, 'neu': 0.263, 'pos': 0.246, 'compound': -0.4215}
CONCLUSION: NEGATIVE
```

`vader_lexicon` and nltk code does a lot more parsing of negation language in sentences in order to negate positive Words. Like when Darth Vader says "lack of faith" that changes the sentiment to its opposite.

I explained it here, with examples of the better results:
https://chewychunks.wordpress.com/2018/06/19/sentiment-analysis-discovering-the-best-way-to-sort-positive-and-negative-feedback/

That replaces this textblob implementation:

```
from textblob import TextBlob
from textblob.sentiments import NaiveBayesAnalyzer
TextBlob("I find your lack of faith disturbing.", analyzer=NaiveBayesAnalyzer())
{'neg': 0.182, 'pos': 0.817, 'combined': 0.635}
CONCLUSION: POSITIVE
```

The vader `nltk` classifier also has additional documentation here on using it for sentiment analysis: http://www.nltk.org/howto/sentiment.html

textBlob always crashed my computer with as little as 5000 examples.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to nltk and vader. In your link to nltk I don't see any info on how to customize the dictionary.

Comment: I don't think I tried customizing Vader's lexicon. I simply used it in place of my custom sentiment models, because it worked better.

Comment: Gotcha. You said "The nltk classifier also has better documentation on how to use your own custom made corpus for sentiment analysis". However, I don't see that info on the page you linked to. I might edit that sentence to "Here are docs on nltk sentiment analysis"

Answer (score 0):

Going over the error message, it seems like the analyzer must be inherited from the abstract class `BaseSentimentAnalyzer`. As mentioned in the docs [here](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/api_reference.html#textblob.en.sentiments.PatternAnalyzer), this class **must** implement the `analyze(text)` function. However, while checking the docs of NLTK's implementation, I could not find this method in it's main documentation [here](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html#nltk.classify.naivebayes.NaiveBayesClassifier) or its parent class `ClassifierI` [here](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.classify.html#nltk.classify.api.ClassifierI). Hence, I believe both these implementations cannot be combined, unless you can implement a new `analyze` function in NLTK's implementation to make it compatible with TextBlob's.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at all the code too, in `nltk` and `textblob` to see how classes were being used by the source, but didn't understand subclassing enough to be sure.

Comment: I am not sure if one can combine the both with a temporary hack, if you can do something or have any updates, please post here :)